# Returning Related (1:M) Django Objects with many as a List

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django and I'm building a Document Visibility/Status application. Each document, called an "Indent", has some "Attributes", and these attributes have multiple "Status".

On the dashboard of the application, I need to dynamically render the attributes as columns, and the statuses as choices in a dropdown list.

I'm thinking that I'll need to return a dictionary as follows - but if you have a better suggestion, please let me know.

```
{ 1 : ['status1','status2', 'status3'], 2 : ['status1','status2', 'status3'], ... }
```

Where the number is the attribute ID.

Here are my models:

```
class Indent(models.Model):
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    indentNumber = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.indentNumber)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Indents'
        verbose_name_plural = "Indents"

class Files(models.Model):
    fileLink = models.FileField(upload_to='indents/', null=True) #Add 'indents/userID'
    indent = models.ForeignKey(Indent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.indent)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Files'
        verbose_name_plural = "Files"

"""
TO-DO

REMOVE NULL CONSTRAINT

"""
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Attributes'
        verbose_name_plural = "Attributes"

"""
TO-DO

For the names of Status objects, it needs to be more descriptive and accurate

"""
class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Status'
        verbose_name_plural = "Status"


class IndentAttribute(models.Model):
    indent_id = models.ForeignKey(Indent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute_id = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status_id = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.indent_id, self.attribute_id)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Indent_Attribute'
        verbose_name_plural = "Indent_Attribute"
```

Here's an example of the dashboard we're building:

[Dashboard Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNmIV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Django's [QuerySet `values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list). Here's a modified example from there to demonstrate how it works:

```
>>> Status.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
<QuerySet ['Okay', 'Not Okay', 'Uh-oh', ...]>
```

You should be able to use that to help construct that dict pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Any ideas if Django has a method to allow me to join two querysets? or should i just write some python code to do it?

Just wondering if there's a simpler way within Django.

Comment: @RizwanQaiser I don't believe you can join two querysets together, but you can convert them to lists with `list(my_queryset)`, then join them together. Hope that helps!

Comment: DOPE! Thanks man. This was my first question at SO and you really helped out. You're an amazing human :)

Comment: @RizwanQaiser Glad I could help! Remember to accept the answer now that you're on the right track.